# Keep all the formulas but delete all the values

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets

How do I keep all the formulas but delete all the values in google script spreadsheet?
OR
How copy only the formulas from a sheet sheet onto another sheet?

Comment: I tried various things but all of them were unsuccessful. Im quite a noob when it comes to spreadsheets. But thanks for your reply man, I am sorry for not replying earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your sheet, select all, and Find and Replace, Replace all within that sheet:

[image: SO32161303 example]

If you end up with `0`s you don't want just do a straight Find `0`, Replace all.